# Refreshing a div using jQuery spoils the layout

Tags: jquery, html

Am using following code to refresh a div, now whenever it refreshes the page, it spoils the layout, am not understanding why so..

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function() {
$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('loadmore.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000);
```

After reloading

[image]

Comment: This is so incomplete. You need to provide more information, especially relevant information! There's no HTML nor CSS in your question. Even though, your problem seems to be in using a wrong "refresh"

Comment: Your code is valid, the problem seems to be that you are appending pages in the wrong div OR that you should append pages without the menu at the top, just the inner content you'd like to replace. Post the markup too.

Comment: You are inserting whole page to an element.

Comment: @Alexander what should I include dude? I am refreshing `<div id="loaddiv">all content is here</div>` that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting whole page to an element, you can pass a selector to `load` method.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
      $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('loadmore.php #target', function(){
           $(this).fadeIn("slow")
      });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I suppose the `loadmore.php` resource should return relevant information for its task, probably you should pinpoint that

Comment: @Alexander Yes, it seems so, result is another #loaddiv within the current #loaddiv element.

Comment: @undefined works bro..Just 1 more question, am loading like twitter, kinda you click on more and the results are fetched, this refresh resets that counter any Idea how can I prevent?

Comment: @RandomGuy Sorry, I don't know how your counter works, if you want to append and not replace the content, you can use `$.get` method instead.